# EncryptByKey function does not work after restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

I've restored my database to a new server and now the EncryptByKey function does not work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using a certificate, if that makes a difference

Comment: Do you get an error message?  If so, then what does it say?  Can you elaborate on "does not work properly"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably broke the [encryption key hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx) as the service master key encryption of your database master key is now gone. Open the database master key using the original encryption password and add the new server service master key encryption:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY;
```